# MySQL foreign keys recursive

Tags: mysql

I have a "categories" table that has a structure:

- categoryId
- parentId
- categoryName

This table represents categorized tree structure where parentId is actually a pointer to categoryId.

Is it possible to put a foreign key RESTRICT to parentId which points to categoryId so that I disable deletion of children nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certainly a table may have a foreign key referencing itself. eg.:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    categoryId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    parentId INTEGER REFERENCES categories(categoryId),
    categoryName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

Naturally you will need to be using InnoDB not MyISAM for this to do anything.

Comment: Thanks but now I have another problem, how do I enter the first record that should be: categoryId = 1, parentId = 0, categoryName = 'test', when there is no categoryId with 0 value.

Comment: Use `NULL` rather than `0` for no parentId.

Comment: Yes NULL works but query is different then. I use a recursive function in php "WHERE parentId=$var" and if is null I need to use "WHERE parentId IS NULL" and that complicates things a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the complication you need to deal with when using self-referencing foreign keys. Your PHP will need to be a little smarter to deal with the root node of the tree as a special case.

Comment: The other solutions are to give the root node itself as a parent, or to have a dummy node above the root node with ID 0. I would stick with the null though. If you're doing a lot of recursive queries for arbitrary-deptch hierarchies, the parent-reference is not a good model; you may want to look at an alternative such as nested sets. See http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html